# Android Studio, use string.xml in java

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using Android Studio. I have a strings.xml like this:

```
<string name="code01">Hello</string>
<string name="code02">Bye</string>
<string name="code03">Moon</string>
<string name="code04">Suun</string>
```

And at my XML, I have something like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/code_a"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

I want, that with a Java variable, to use one of these strings, on my XML. I tried this, at my `OnCreate()` Java function:

```
TextView var01;
var01 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.code_a);
var01.setText("@string/code"+var02);
```

With `var02` having possible values of `"01"`, `"02"`, `"03"`, and `"04"`.
But this doesn´t work. What can I try?

Comment: I think it's because `@string/code04` is replaced by the compiler.

Comment: When I use (for exameple, var02 = "01"), that would must show "Hello", but it shows "@string/code01".

Comment: try this :                                                                                                   String temp= getResources().getString(R.string.code01);        

    TextView var01 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.code_a);
    var01.setText(temp);

Comment: "code01", is at the example the value of "name", on strings.xml. Right? When I do it, it doesn´t reknow it.

Comment: Doesn´t work, because, I haven´t "code01", I have "code", and "01", is a variable. and, if I write:

getResources().getString(R.string."code"+VAR);

Doesn´t work